# How to update in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new at Mongoose/nodejs and I am struggling with a simple update of an array within an array.

Here's the schema:

```
var County = new Schema({
_id                 : Schema.ObjectId,
name                : String,
biggestCity         : String
});

var Country = new Schema({
_id                 : Schema.ObjectId,
name                : String,
counties                : {type: [County], ref: "County"}
});

var Continent = new Schema({
    _id       : Schema.ObjectId,
    countries : {type: [Country], ref: "Country"},
});
```

And here's the update code I've been trying:

```
var continents = mongoose.model("Continent");
var update = { "countries.counties.name": newName, "countries.counties.biggestCity": newBiggestCity };
var conditions = { "_id": countryId, "countries.name": countryName, "countries.counties.name": countyName };
var options = { multi: false }; 
wagers.update(conditions, update, options, function(err, numAffected) {
    //callback code...
});
```

When doing this, the error in err says "Can't append to array using string field name 'counties'". What does this mean? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the child object as another Schema, not just as a list of some anonymous object. ([Reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongoose-orm/Papuwduny3Q/FKYXE84UUk0J).)

Try defining `Country` as a separate Schema, nest that in `Continent`, then do your update.

Comment: Ok. Is there not any alternative way to update the nested array, without having to re-define the schema?

Comment: @tremolo: there may or may not (my Mongoose-fu is still weak), but I think it's good practice to define a schema for `Country` anyway.

Comment: SOLVED! The update parameter should only specify the property to update as "name" and not "countries.counties.name".